# can I use Java Mission Control to monitor older JVMs?

Tags: java, monitoring, jmc

Can I use Java Mission Control to monitor an older JVM, like 1.7.0_u2?

The program tells me that I can't use the Flight Recorder but is there a problem or limit with the rest of monitoring options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/jmc-5-3-certified-system-config-2159573.html

1. Java SE **7 Update 4** and above can be monitored by Java Mission
   Control 5.3.
2. Prior versions of Java SE, 1.4.2, 5.0 and 6, cannot be
   monitored by Java Mission Control 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Regular JMX monitoring should work fine.